# Prolog Why is the multiplication symbol * an undefined procedure?

Tags: prolog, multiplication

I am trying to do simple two number multiplication in Prolog. When I initially launch Prolog without loading any file, I am able to type in:

```
X is 2 * 2.
```

And I get 4 as the answer. But when I launch Prolog by opening my file with my code, the above statement does not work anymore. It says:

```
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: (*)/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

And when I load my code I get the following:

```
Warning: The predicates below are not defined. If these are defined
Warning: at runtime using assert/1, use :- dynamic Name/Arity.
Warning: 
Warning: */2, which is referenced by
Warning:        c:/filepath/project.pl:98:21: 1-st       clause of multiply/3
```

Why does the multiplication work when I don't load my code, but not work when I load my code? This is part of the code I am using for multiplication:

```
:-dynamic(multiply/3).
multiply(X, Y, Z) :- Z is X * Y.
```

The two lines above are the only mentions of multiply in my code.
I have spent a couple hours searching for answers and failed. Maybe my keywords I use to search are not specific enough, but it's difficult to find Prolog answers as it is. Am I doing something wrong? This issue is the only thing preventing me from finishing my project, which is too long to be of good use if posted.

Comment: Could be you have some unclosed comment(s) **above** the error location ?

Comment: I figured it out. It was something really dumb. The Professor gave us code. Our job was to modify it to make it do something else. I believe he redefined 'is' by doing the ':-op(150,xfx,is).'  so it lost its meaning (im assuming if i understand it correctly). And when he redefined it, it wasn't used anywhere else which makes absolutely no sense to me. I removed that line and everything worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of our project was to modify code given by the Professor. The Prof included the following line that was not being used anywhere:

```
:-op(150,xfx,is).
```

When removed, the 'is' in:

```
  X is 2 * 2.
```

works and displays the correct answer.

Comment: Great that you sorted this out. Please accept your answer so that this is marked as solved.